# Loop function for a check out program in python

Tags: python, loops

My teacher wants this code to run on a loop but I am not sure how to do that. Can anyone help me please?

```
ask = input("Enter only one name of the item bought like Potatoes, Ham, AppleJuice, or Gatorade: ")

if ask == "potatoes":
    def potatoes (quantity, price=5.99):
        total = quantity * price
        while True:
         if quantity > 15:
            print("Congratulations, you are eligible for 11% discount")
            totalWithDiscount = total - (0.08 * total)
            print("your total with 8% discount and no tax: $", totalWithDiscount)
            print("Visit us soon!!")
            return (0.879 * totalWithDiscount) + totalWithDiscount
        
    else:
        print("sorry, you are not eligible for 11% discount")

        print("your total with 11% discount and no tax: $", total)
        return (0.879 * total) + total
        print("Sorry, you are only eligible for discount, if you buy more than 15 Lbs. of Potatoes. ")
        print("Total without discount and no Tax $", total)
        print("Your Total with Tax: 5.29% is $", tax3)
        print("Thank you, for being Walmart' Valuable Shopper.")
        print("Visit us soon!!")

potatoes(int(input("Enter the quantity of Potatoes you bought : ")), 8.99)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very wrong and it will not run, but I have an idea of what you are trying to do, so this will work

```
def potatoes (quantity, price=5.99):
    total = quantity * price
    if quantity > 15:
        print("Congratulations, you are eligible for 11% discount")
        totalWithDiscount = total - (0.08 * total)
        print("your total with 8% discount and no tax: $", totalWithDiscount)
        print("Visit us soon!!")
        return (0.879 * totalWithDiscount) + totalWithDiscount
    else:
        print("sorry, you are not eligible for 11% discount")
    
        print("your total with 11% discount and no tax: $", total)
        tax3 = (0.879 * total) + total
        print("Sorry, you are only eligible for discount, if you buy more than 15 Lbs. of Potatoes. ")
        print("Total without discount and no Tax $", total)
        print("Your Total with Tax: 5.29% is $", tax3)
        print("Thank you, for being Walmart' Valuable Shopper.")
        print("Visit us soon!!")

while True:
    ask = input("Enter only one name of the item bought like Potatoes, Ham, AppleJuice, or Gatorade: ")
    
    if ask == "potatoes":
        number_of_potatoes = int(input("Enter the quantity of Potatoes you bought : "))
        
        potatoes(number_of_potatoes, 8.99)
    else:
        print('Thank you visiting')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little bit confusing but i hope this is what you intended for.

1.I moved the function definition out of the loop, and it is inside the loop that you call it so the code inside the function can be reused as many times as you need!

2.I also changed the loop condition for when the user inserts "no" so there's an end to it, but change for whatever you want

3.About the return statement it's important to remember that when it's executed the function that it is within ends and return the designated value, everything after it won't be executed, that's why i moved it to the end.

4.And finally there's a variable tax3 that isn't being defined anywhere in your code, maybe you didn't put it here or maybe you just forgot about it, so you need to fix it or delete it so the code works. Hope i understood your question, good programming!

```
def potatoes (quantity, price=5.99):
        total = quantity * price
        if quantity > 15:
            print("Congratulations, you are eligible for 11% discount")
            totalWithDiscount = total - (0.08 * total)
            print("your total with 8% discount and no tax: $", totalWithDiscount)
            print("Visit us soon!!")
            return (0.879 * totalWithDiscount) + totalWithDiscount
        
        else:
            print("sorry, you are not eligible for 11% discount")
            print("your total with 11% discount and no tax: $", total)
            print("Sorry, you are only eligible for discount, if you buy more than 15 Lbs. of Potatoes. ")
            print("Total without discount and no Tax $", total)
            print("Your Total with Tax: 5.29% is $", tax3)
            print("Thank you, for being Walmart' Valuable Shopper.")
            print("Visit us soon!!")
            return (0.879 * total) + total

ask = input("Enter only one name of the item bought like Potatoes, Ham, AppleJuice, or Gatorade: ")

while(ask != "no"):
    if ask == "potatoes":
        potatoes(int(input("Enter the quantity of Potatoes you bought : ")), 8.99)
    ask = input("Enter only one name of the item bought like Potatoes, Ham, AppleJuice, or Gatorade: ")
```

Comment: Thank you Rickesta! I am just learning python so this was very helpful.

Comment: No problem @MinMin ! Glad i helped, please mark my answer as the solution so others with the same problem can come here and check it out